# Is there an easy way with activerecord to get the total count for a query?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I have the following query:

```
@jobs = Job.where(publisher_id: params[:publisher_id], status: status).order(order_by => order_dir).offset(start).limit(limit)
```

I want to be able to get the total number of results for it. The easy way is to do this:

```
@jobs = Job.where(publisher_id: params[:publisher_id], status: status).count
```

However, is there a way to just include the total results with the query? I know there's the kaminari gem (and will_paginate) but there must be a simple way to include this is the response, is there not?

What I'm looking for is a way to make this a single query if possible.

Comment: what is the expected output?

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely yes, you can do something like this:

```
@jobs = Job.where(publisher_id: params[:publisher_id], status: status).select('*, COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY id) AS count')
count = @jobs.first.count
```

I'm using [window function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/tutorial-window.html) to achieve this!

Comment: what happens though when I'm using a limit on the initial query thought?